# Including standalone browserify bundle into main bundle

Tags: javascript, browserify

My browserify project is dependent on another browserify bundle, which uses standalone bundling. [According to docs (on jquery example)](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#excluding) I'm supposed to include it as a separate file. But I'd like to have my project in single file (as are my automatisation tools set up at the mooment). If I don't exclude it, my browserify fails to build as it complains about requires to nonexistant paths within dependency.

Is there a simple way to incorporate standalone build into my bundle?

Project I'm dependent on is Matterjs [(link to this specific build)](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/build/matter.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Add this to your browserify config:

```
{
    noParse: [require.resolve('matter-js')]
}
```